# Unity linerenderer error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drawing, paint

I am making a drawing app in Unity and I'm using line renderer. Here's the code, the problem is every time I make new line with another color it's drawing in back of the first color. Can somebody help me out? I just don't know how to fix.

I was thinking about adding a little bit more z position to the line renderer when I switch colors, but I'm not sure it's going to work.

```
    public GameObject lineDrawPrefabs;
    public Material black;
    public Material green1;
    public Material blue;
    public Material pink;
    public Material orange;
    public Material brown;
    public Material green2;
    public Material blue2;
    public Material yellow;
    public Material red;
    public Material white;

    public static string nowcolor;
    private bool isMousePressed;
    private GameObject lineDrawPrefab;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    List<Vector3> drawPoints = new List<Vector3>();

   // public static bool pencil;



    void Start()
    {

        isMousePressed = false;     
    }


    void Update()
    {
      //  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
      //  {
       //     // delete the LineRenderers when right mouse down
       //     GameObject[] delete = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("LineDraw");
        //    int deleteCount = delete.Length;
        //    for (int i = deleteCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        //        Destroy(delete[i]);
      //  }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // left mouse down, make a new line renderer
            isMousePressed = true;
            lineDrawPrefab = GameObject.Instantiate(lineDrawPrefabs) as GameObject;
            lineRenderer = lineDrawPrefab.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
            CheckColor();
            lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(0);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            // left mouse up, stop drawing
            isMousePressed = false;
            drawPoints.Clear();
        }

        if (isMousePressed)
        {
            // when the left mouse button pressed
            // continue to add vertex to line renderer
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            mousePos.z = -1000;
            if (!drawPoints.Contains(mousePos))
            {
                drawPoints.Add(mousePos);
                lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(drawPoints.Count);
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(drawPoints.Count - 1, mousePos);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void deletedrawing() {
        //     // delete the LineRenderers when right mouse down
           GameObject[] delete = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("LineDraw");
           int deleteCount = delete.Length;
           for (int i = deleteCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
           Destroy(delete[i]);
    }
```

[Here is the image,first time I used the black color,then the green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbW8U.png)

Comment: Can you provide an annotated picture indicating what the problem is? I think for visual issues, that kind of information would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue,I just used order in layer,added +1 every time the user choose a color,now it's working fine

Added this to the main script

```
 public static int orderinlayer = 1;
```

And added lineRenderer.sortingOrder = orderinlayer; here

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isMousePressed = true;
            lineDrawPrefab = GameObject.Instantiate(lineDrawPrefabs) as GameObject;
            lineRenderer = lineDrawPrefab.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
            lineRenderer.sortingOrder = orderinlayer;
            CheckColor();
            lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(0);
        }
```

And from another script what is the color picker i just added

```
ScriptLineGameobject.orderinlayer += 1;
```

for each `color.Now` its working!